# What does VM_MIXEDMAP and VM_PFNMAP flags mean in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

These two flags are used by drivers, but I don't understand why we need them. What would happen if I don't set these two flags on VMA? When should I use them? Could someone give some usecases? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation for `VM_MIXEDMAP`, and indirectly for `VM_PFNMAP`, comes from the description of patch submission that introduced it:
http://visa.lab.asu.edu/gitlab/fstrace/android-kernel-msm-hammerhead-3.4-marshmallow-mr3/commit/b379d790197cdf8a95fb67507d75a24ac0a1678d

In short, `VM_MIXEDMAP` allows a mapping to contain both "managed" pages (i.e. controlled by memory manager) and "unmanaged" pages (i.e. given "as is", like physical devices). `VM_PFNMAP` is for "completely unmanaged" areas, whose resources are not controlled by the normal allocation system (e.g., again, like physical devices mapped in user space).

Both flags are for very special use, `VM_PFNMAP` is discussed here: https://linux-mm.org/DeviceDriverMmap

In my opinion it is unlikely that in "normal" device drivers happen to use `VM_MIXEDMAP`.

Comment: Is VM_PFNMAP a **subset** of VM_MIXEDMAP?

Comment: Sort of... but I think that the latter is reserved for very "internal" cases, in particular optimizaitions based on copy-on-write mechanism etc...